# How can I get elementbyname via webbrowser control?

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control, dom

I need to fill inputs via webbrowser. When i try to getelementbyname i am getting null value. Could you please help me solve this problem?

```
<input onfocus="showInfoBox(this, "Varchar(100) Latin capital letters only (A-Z) and spaces between surnames")" onblur="hideInfoBox()" value="" name="Surname"><input>
```

Here is my code:

```
    public HtmlElementCollection GetElemByName(string name)
    {
        if (webBrowser1.Document == null)
            return null;

        HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;

        return doc.All.GetElementsByName(name);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlElementCollection col = GetElemByName("Surname");
        if (col != null && col.Count > 0)
        {
            col[0].SetAttribute("Surname", "My Surname");
        }             
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no attribute Surname.

You should change:

```
col[0].SetAttribute("name", "My Surname");
```

Attribute is: `name`,`id`, `type` and etc ...

In your case this was name. Also you should add type of your `input`. Probably the type is `text`

```
<input type="text" onfocus="showInfoBox(this, "Varchar(100) Latin capital letters only (A-Z) and spaces between surnames")" onblur="hideInfoBox()" value="" name="Surname"><input>
```

Also what is the value of `webBrowser1`, I hope it is not null !

Comment: Hi again, i change attribute "name" but still doesnt work(returns col.count=0). Can you explain please can i add type to input? Because it is not my web site. I just need fill inputs and perform click on any website, not mine.

Comment: You should check what is the value of webBrowser1. Use debug and check it !

Comment: No, its not null. webbrowser1 = System.Windows.Forms.Webrowser, webBrowser1.document = System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument